# Cannot reolve symbol "@drawable/", imagem existe e aplicação roda ok

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

O Android Studio mostra este aviso, porém a aplicação roda normal e a imagem é mostrada normalmente.

Minha dúvida é porque a IDE mostra o erro se está tudo ok.

Imagem na pasta:

[image: Imagem existe na estrutura]

Erro no XML:

[image: Erro no XML]

Existe algum lugar que devo informar o nome do arquivo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rogerio, voce esta usando qual versao de Android Studio? Canary? o que pode acontecer as vezes é sua app funcionar porque Android Studio tem algo em cache que faz funcionar ou como voce diz que esta tudo certo, apenas a mensagem errada, algumas vezes acontece da cache de Android Studio ter alguma coisa errada. Se voce faz un Build -> Clean Project e depois que terminar faz um Build -> Rebuild Project não resolve? eu tentaria tambem um File -> Invalidate cache / restart. Quando troco muito de branch no git e existe diferença de versao de dependency ou de resource as vezes o meu fica com problemas parecidos com o seu. Eu uso sempre a ultima build de Canary então me espero alguns pequenos problemas do tipo.

Comment: "File -> Invalidate cache / restart" funcionou! Apesar de não afetar a aplicação, sempre ia ver qual era o erro e lembrava que "não era nada". Valeu!